# How to remove spaces from list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following input:

```
[ ['A(x) | B(x)'],['Function(x,y) | K(x)'] ]
```

Each list within the list of list has a space before and after the character "|". How can I remove this to get the following result?

```
[ ['A(x)|B(x)'],['Function(x,y)|K(x)'] ]
```

I tried the following:

```
list=[]
k1=[]
for i in sentence:
    k1="".join(i).replace(" ","")
    list.append(k1)

result=[[i] for i in list]
```

Comment: @coldspeed It's a nested list of strings, of course it's possible for those strings to have whitespace.

Comment: @Gayathri pls post your attempts.

Comment: @roganjosh Did I misread? Their initial post mentioned white space after "[", which misled me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I have updated my question

Comment: Split by ” | ” and Rhen join by ””

Comment: `[re.sub(r'\s+\|\s+', '|', s) for s in input]` for any number of whitespace and only around `'|'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> a_list = [['A(x) | B(x)'], ['Function(x,y) | K(x)']]
>>> result = [[''.join(''.join(sub).split())] for sub in a_list]
>>> result
[['A(x)|B(x)'], ['Function(x,y)|K(x)']]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!